# Symfony in prod auto redirects to "/web"

Tags: php, apache, symfony

After releasing my Symfony project to the production server if I navigate to `/` I'm automatically redirected to `/web` and all the other paths need to have `/web/<something>` to work.

On localhost I don't have this problem, but I think that the installtron instance of my hosting space made some mess.

I though the Apache's `httpd.conf` is wrong, but the hosting provider told that everything's ok.

Comment: The domain name for your project should be pointed to /web already. Are you using a domain name to access this project and that is where you have the problem? Also, using a webhost instead of a server host limits your control over the php configuration, maybe there is an extension missing or something.

Comment: Can you get a copy of the `httpd.conf` file from the hosting provider?